# How to disable firefox tabs titles updates?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Firefox tabs change automatically. On Facebook if you have a notification, or on any site that refreshes itself automatically. I would like to prevent that.

Is it possible to configure Firefox to do so? Or should I look for a plugin which could disable only some Javascript (disable use of document.title), because I believe that titles and page refreshs are done using Javascript mainly?

I find it distracting and frustrating to see a tab title blink for nothing. I believe my best option would be to use the fullscreen mode more often but I don't want to press F11 anytime I read something on a page.